# elasticsearch-dsl Document field name serialization with a different name

Tags: elasticsearch-dsl

How can I serialize the field name with a different name from what is defined in the Document object?

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Document, Text

class MyDocument(Document):
     context = Text()
```

When saving this document to ES, I want to write the 'context' key as '@context'.

Answer (score 0):

Since `@context` is not a valid python identifier I am afraid this is not easily possible. You can always drop down to the raw json (by overriding the `to_dict` method) but I would definitely not recommend it.

Comment: Is it not easily possible to create a custom field (inheriting from `Field` class) and then override the `to_dict` method?